# Amazon SES fails even on verified domain using SMTP

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, smtp, amazon-ses

I'm trying to send through Amazon SES using SMTP.

I'm in production, as you can see: http://to.fbrz.io/1X5Q7LS

And I've a verified domain: http://to.fbrz.io/1O0qf3D

But the verified domain is being ignored, I'm able to send email only if I verify the specific sender address.

What I'm doing wrong? Heeeeeeeelp!

Comment: Have you made sure that you verified the domain in all the regions for the endpoints you are using? Is it possible the individual email address is verified for the right region, but the domain is not?

Comment: If domain has been verified, then you should be fine to send mail with any mailbox "XXX@domainname.com". if not, enable SNS to get the bounced or complain notification to another mailbox which you confirm the mailbox is exist, for example, to gmail.

Answer (score 0):

Lesson learned: never understimate your ability to make mistakes.

Because the software I use to send email reconfigure the sender in order to take advantage of VERB protocol to add information using the software server domain, I needed to verify both.

This solved the issue.

Thank you all for the answers.